# The End of File Error in PHP

Tags: php, pdo

I get the unexpected end of file error when I run this file.Below is the code.

```html
<?php 

include_once('/templates/header.php');
include_once('/admin/includes/db_connect.php');

session_start();

$last_id;

$first_name=$_POST['firstname'];//this values comes from html file after submitting 

$last_name=$_POST['lastname']; 

$request=$_POST['request'];

$purpose=$_POST['purposebuttons']; 

$accessedby = $_POST['personbuttons'];

 $description=$_POST['description']; 

$accessdate = $_POST['date-time'];


/* Get Current Date and Time for the bookking_time field */
$booking_time=new DateTime();
$booking_time = $booking_time -> format("Y-m-d H:i:s");

 $stmt= $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO data_centre_users (first_name,last_name,request, purpose , accessed_by, description,booking_time,access_time)
          values(:first_name,:last_name,:request,:purpose, :accessedby ,:description, NOW() , :accessdate); 
    
    values('$first_name','$last_name','$request','$purpose', '$accessedby' ,'$description', NOW() , '$accessdate')); 

$stmt->bindParam(':first_name', $first_name); 
$stmt->bindParam(':last_name', $last_name); 
$stmt->bindParam(':request', $request); 
$stmt->bindParam(':purpose', $purpose); 
$stmt->bindParam(':accessedby', $accessedby);
$stmt->bindParam(':description', $description);
$stmt->bindParam(':accessdate', $accessdate); 

if ($stmt->execute() === TRUE) {
   $last_id = $dbh->lastInsertId();

    echo 'New record created successfully'.'<BR>';
   echo '<a href='insert_result.php'>View result</a>';

} else {
    
}


header ('Location: insert_result.php');
 exit();
?>
```

Comment: your missing a `"` in this line `$stmt= $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO data_centre_users (first_name,last_name,request, purpose , accessed_by, description,booking_time,access_time)
          values(:first_name,:last_name,:request,:purpose, :accessedby ,:description, NOW() , :accessdate); 
    
    values('$first_name','$last_name','$request','$purpose', '$accessedby' ,'$description', NOW() , '$accessdate')" <--- Right Here); 
`

Comment: Even SO's code formatter is able to find the error. You forgot to close a quote and everything starting that point until the end of file is interpreted as a(n incomplete) string.

Answer (score 0):

Your query line doesn't have a closing quotation mark. Change this line:

```
$stmt= $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO data_centre_users (first_name,last_name,request, purpose , accessed_by, description,booking_time,access_time)
values(:first_name,:last_name,:request,:purpose, :accessedby ,:description, NOW() , :accessdate);
values('$first_name','$last_name','$request','$purpose', '$accessedby' ,'$description', NOW() , '$accessdate'));
```

To:

```
$stmt= $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO data_centre_users (first_name,last_name,request, purpose , accessed_by, description,booking_time,access_time)
values(:first_name,:last_name,:request,:purpose, :accessedby ,:description, NOW() , :accessdate);
values('$first_name','$last_name','$request','$purpose', '$accessedby' ,'$description', NOW() , '$accessdate')");
```